# viewForHeader with dynamic height?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am returning a view with dynamic height for `viewForHeader` in `table views`.I have 2 section.But I am getting a view that is for header section 1 in section 0 and for section 1 no view is coming blank space is coming.Below is the code.

```
        tblList.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100
        tblList.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 2
        }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        print("Section: \(section)")
            let view = UIView()
            let lbl = UILabel()
           view.backgroundColor = UIColor.LGColor()

            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
            lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(lbl)
            lbl.font = UIFont.subHeadline

            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lbl, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 3))

            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lbl, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lbl, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10))

            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lbl, attribute: .height, relatedBy:.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 21))

            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: lbl, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 3))


   view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: tableView.frame.size.width))

        if section == 0 {
            view.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
        return view
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you set `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false`, comment that line and check if you can see both sections

Answer (score 1):

It's happens because you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for header view, remove this line

Its remove constraints created in `TableView` and two views have origin `point {0, 0}`

[image]